# How can i disable/enable form based on dropdown value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have two forms on the same page. I want to enable/disable a form element based on the drop down value selected on the first form.

On the first drop down When option 1 selected or `<option  value="">Select</option>` I want to disable the second dropdown from the first form or `<select name="tractor" ..>` and everything on **2nd Form** form.

if from `<select name="tire">`: `Rear Tire` or `Front Tire` selected but Nothing selected in the second dropdown i want to enable `<select name="tractor">` and keep **2nd Form** disable.

**1st Form**

```
<form method="post">
<select name="tire">
    <option  value="">Select</option>
    <option  value="rear">Rear Tire</option>
    <option  value="front">Front Tire</option>
</select> 
 <select name="tractor">
    <option value="">select Type</option>
    <option value="2wd">2WD</option>
    <option value="mfwd">MFWD</option>
    <option value="4wd">4WD</option>
 </select>
 <input type="submit" value="Go" name="cmd_submit" />
```

**2nd Form** // want to be disabled when page loads

```
 <form method="post" id="vehicle" action="page.php">
      .
      .
      .
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply check the value of the first dropdown. I added some classes to the dropdowns `first` and `second`:

```
<h3> First form </h3>
<form method="post" class="firstform">
  <select name="tire" class="first">
    <option  value="">Select</option>
    <option  value="rear">Rear Tire</option>
    <option  value="front">Front Tire</option>
  </select> 
  <select name="tractor" class="second" disabled>
    <option value="">select Type</option>
    <option value="2wd">2WD</option>
    <option value="mfwd">MFWD</option>
    <option value="4wd">4WD</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Go" name="cmd_submit" />
</form>

<h3> Second form </h3>
<form method="post" id="vehicle" action="page.php" class="secondform">
   <label>A form with no fields is useless: </label>
   <input type="text" placeholder="so here a field" class="secondformfield" />  <br />
   <label>This is a dropdown: </label>
   <select name="tractor" class="secondformfield">
    <option value="">...</option>
    <option value="2wd">With an option</option>
    <option value="mfwd">And another option</option>
   </select>  <br />
   <textarea class="secondformfield">some text</textarea>
   <input type="button" value="And away!" name="cmd_away" class="secondformfield"/> 
</form>
```

And the Js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".secondform .secondformfield").prop("disabled",true);

    $(".first").change(function(){
      if($(this).val() !== ""){
        $(".second").prop("disabled",false);
      }
      else{
        $(".second").prop("disabled",true);
      }

      checkIfEverythingIsFilledIn();
    });

    $(".second").change(function(){
      checkIfEverythingIsFilledIn();
    });

    function checkIfEverythingIsFilledIn(){
      if($(".first").val() !== "" && $(".second").val() !== ""){
        $(".secondform .secondformfield").prop("disabled",false);
        $(".secondform").attr("method","post").attr("action","page.php");
      }
      else{
        $(".secondform .secondformfield").prop("disabled",true);
        $(".secondform").removeAttr("method").removeAttr("action");
      }
    }
});
```

For preventing the submit of the form there are multiple solutions. The submitbutton will be disabled automatically because it is also of type `input`. Another option is to remove/add the attributes of the form like I did above [and in a JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wbxth2ao/35/)

Edit: Updated js code by a good advise of @WorldFS

Comment: according to jQuery doc, $().prop("disabled",true) and $().prop("disabled",false) should be used instead of .attr(), see http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: how can i endable and disable the second form ` <form method="post" id="vehicle" action="page.php">`?

Comment: but the form is on the same page is not in different page

Comment: I was in the understanding these forms are on seperated pages. This changes the solution a bit, but I need more info. What do you want to disable on the second form? The fields? The submit button? Both?

Comment: the form and the whole elements enabled if  both dropdown !=""

Comment: @Pazcal de Jonge Thanks for the help and for some reason the second drop down stuck disabled. i put it as follows  `<script type="text/javascript">
$(".first").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() !== ""){
   $(".second").prop("disabled",false);
  }
  else{
  $(".second").prop("disabled",true);
  }
});
</script>

Comment: I've updated the code above. If you check the JsFiddle you should have a working version. In which scenario stays the 2nd dropdown disabled?

Comment: @Pazcal de Jonge  Smart only one thing i have dropdown on the form that still active everything works greate except dropdowns on the second form need to be disable/enabled

Comment: Nice catch... In my example I only focussed myself on the input fields only as I didn't know what was in the second form. I've updated the above and the jsfiddle for multiple form elements. By using the class 'secondformfield' I toggle the enable/disable statusses of the formfields on the second form